# Scheduler in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have some pictures which are part different groups (directories) on Ubuntu. I use Wordpress to show them on a webpage. (I use Wordpress only so I can use its member/login management plugins). I would want to schedule these groups based on time-slots (eg. time of day, which day of week and season etc) so that a particular group is shown to the visitors based on time-slot. I am not using standard plugins as it may lead to a lock-in as my requirements grow. I would prefer PHP for a boilerplate implementation. Want to further grow it to have an admin panel where logged-in users can upload pics, associate to groups and time-slots and a UI that shows relevant pics based on user and time-slot.

Comment: you can use the WP Booking Calendar plugin - https://wpbookingcalendar.com/

Comment: I want to be able to invoke some php or some event call-back when the time-slot arrives based on the Calendar day+time and change the picture group in the backend. Is that possible?